# merge string with text field and return to a label in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

Currently this is just passing data from textField from first viewController to a label in second viewController. I want to concatenate a string before this textField to show it in Label.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    //var abs = "Greetings"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destviewcontroller : PassData = segue.destination as! PassData

        destviewcontroller.textLabel = textField.text!
        /* i want to add a string before this textField text to show it in label,
           for example "Greeings (whatever in textField)." */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
destviewcontroller.textLabel.text = "Greeings \(textField.text!)"
```

But you should consider unwrapping that `textField.text` like this

```
if let text = textField.text {
    destviewcontroller.textLabel.text = "Greeings \(text)" 
}
```

So your app won't crash if textField.text is empty :D

Comment: Thanks dude, thanks a lot, did exactly what I need, cheers :D (thumbsUp)

Comment: @Kartic No problem! Don't forget if this is what helped you to mark it as the solution. Gives me them sweet internet points I'm working for ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if let text = textField.text {
     destviewcontroller.textLabel.text = "Greeings (whatever in \(text))."
}
```